# Using mouse in Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Terminal Inside VMWare

Tags: 14.04, mouse, vmware, virtual-terminal

I need to use mouse pointer and click functionality while using virtual terminal in Ubuntu 14.40 running on VMWare virtual machine. I've installed gpm with this command

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

but I can't see the mouse pointer. Is there any step I have to do to make it work or another way beside using gpm?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a VMWare user but there could possibly be 3 issues:

1. Your copy of VMWare could be quite old and suffering a known bug with mouse use
2. You have set the text display to more than 100%. If so:

   1. Right-click anywhere on the client/host desktop and click Personalize.
   2. Click Display.
   3. Select 100%.
3. You have incorrectly set the mouse 'grabbing' behaviour that is set in: *Edit --> Preferences --> Input*

Hopefully attention to these 3 issues will resolve your mouse issues...

**References:**

- [Mouse pointer movement within a VMware Workstation virtual machine does not match the mouse position when text display size is increased](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016158)
- [Setting Preferences for VMware Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_prefs_ws.html)